# Assign std:wstring to VCL UnicodeString most effectively

Tags: c++builder

I have a range of `std::wstring` objects that need to be displayed and hence stored in various VCL objects.

I have looked in the documentation for a VCL `String` `Assign()` function, preferably one that takes a `count` as input but cannot find it.

What I do now:

```
my_vcl_object->Caption = my_wstring_text.c_str() ;
```

From what I can see in the documentation, the VCL `String` `operator=()` takes a `reference` to `String` as input.

Does this mean that currently:

1. a (temp) VCL String object is created using the `wchar_t` pointer during construction ?
2. And hence all characters are counted till the `NULL` character
3. And next the `Caption` `String` copies the content of the temp. `String` ?

Or is there an undocumented `operator=()` for String that takes a `wchar_t` pointer and hence avoids step 1 ?

And what about step 2.  Is there a VCL function I can use to use the wstring `length()` as input to avoid having to count the characters each time ?  So that `Caption` can simply copy the memory essentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Caption` is a `String`, which maps to `AnsiString` in C++Builder 2007 and earlier, and to `UnicodeString` in C++Builder 2009 and later.

The `=` assignment operator takes a whole `String` as input. So yes, your 3 points of analysis are correct. In your example, a temp `String` gets constructed and copied from.

However, `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` both have a constructor that accepts 2 parameters as input, a pointer to the character data and a length, so you can construct the temp `String` explicitly with more than 1 parameter, eg:

```cpp
my_vcl_object->Caption = String(my_wstring_text.c_str(), my_wstring_text.length());
```

Comment: Thanks Remy.  One step avoided.  Isn't this a missed chance in VCL ?  An entire memory allocation / memory copy could be avoided.  Anyways, thanks !

Comment: "*An entire memory allocation / memory copy could be avoided*" - no, not avoided, merely optimized. The code still has to make a copy of the `wstring` data, it just doesn't have to waste time calculating the length since it is already known ahead of time. A real missed opportunity would be if they had provided a copy-on-write `UnicodeString` implementation that could initially point to a user-defined memory block rather than an internally allocated block. But that is never going to happen since it is not compatible with Delphi.

Comment: ` The code still has to make a copy of the wstring data` - Right.  But does it not do that twice ?  First constructing the temp `String`, and next when copying the temp string content to the `Caption` String of the visual object ?

Comment: @Peter No, because `String` is reference counted. There will only be 1 copy made, when the temp `String` is created. Then the `Caption` will increment the `String` data's refcount on assignment, and then the temp will decrement the refcount when destroyed. Now, of course, there may be another copy created internally when the new `Caption` gets assigned to the underlying UI control at the OS layer, but that is an implementation detail. Things like `TLabel` won't do that, they will just use the `Caption` as-is during painting.